# Open file as a tab in vim with double click

Tags: ubuntu, vim

Could anyone suggest me how to open multiple files in a vim with a double click from filesystem. 
Currently I can open multiple files in vim using:

1. :tabe
2. NERDTree file navigation
3. using gVim

But I don't like these solutions. All I want is a simple technique that when I double click a file, will open as a new tab in a vim instead of a new terminal instance of vim. The mechanism simple code-editors like sublime-text follows for example.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see this working. Vim runs in the terminal and I guess you're double clickung in some file manager, right? I dont't think this "link" can be made.
What I usually do is "vim foo.*" and then ":tab all" in vim. Also, typing ":tabnew bar" in vim shouldn't be much slower (actually it should be faster) than grabbing the mouse and double clicking.

Comment: @fpnick - you are right, its fast to open when the file is in same directory using :tabe but when I have to go to completely different folder its little bit harder.

Answer (score 0):

Vim has a [`:help client-server`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/remote.txt.html#client-server) feature built-in. For terminal Vim, this needs access to the X server ([`:help x11-clientserver`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/remote.txt.html#x11-clientserver)), and you need explicitly specify a servername when launching Vim:

```
$ vim --servername target
```

Then, in a different terminal (or via a shell script that you register for "double-clicks from filesystem", e.g. via a Nautilus plugin), you can make the first Vim edit passed file(s):

```
$ vim --servername target --remote /path/to/file [...]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is not what I want, I want a simple feature like opening multiple files in gedit in tabs from double click on filesystem. But I will stick to NerdTree for now.

Comment: Well, what looks like a simple feature in other editors usually involves a similar kind of inter-process communication; it's just better hidden from you. The things I've outlined are not that complex (if you know what to do) - of course, you're free to skip the learning experience for now if you have another working alternative.